# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I am getting the following error when I try to encode an object.

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'

The definition of this object is as under:-

```
public struct Item: Codable {
    public var _id: Int
    public var name: String
    public var price: Float

    public init(_id: Int, name: String, price: Float) {
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }    

    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case _id = "id"
        case name
        case price
    }
}
```

And I am trying to encode it by:

```
public func createDictionaryRequestForAddingItems(item : Item)->Data{
    let dictRequest = ["item":item];
    let dataRequest = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictRequest, options: []);
    return dataRequest;
}
```

If instead of an item object I use a simple object like a String or an Int directly, then it all works, but when the request needs an `Item` object (which IS-A `Codable` instance) then it gives the above error.

`JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(item)` always gives false, even for the requests that getting properly getting encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to combine two types of JSON encoding. `JSONSerialization` and `Codable`. `JSONSerialization` has nothing to do with `Codable`.

Actually, you want something like this:

```
public func createDictionaryRequestForAddingItems(item: Item) -> Data {
   let dictRequest = ["item": item]
   let dataRequest = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dictRequest)
   return dataRequest
}
```

`JSONSerialization` can encode only the following types: `Array`, `Dictionary`, `String`, `Bool` and numeric types (e.g. `Double`, `Int`).

Comment: *JSONSerialization has nothing to do with Codable* is a pretty bold statement 

Comment: @vadian Well, it doesn't :)